Unable to modify Rprofile.site
I am trying to modify my RProfile.site in order to ad a line of code and specify in which library I would like to install packages.
I have tried to follow the steps in this post text but when I use the VIM editor I get a message saying that Rprofile.site is only for reading and cannot write there.
So, I started to install packages using this line of code in a my local R_Directory:
install.packages("ComplexHeatmap", lib = "C:/path/to/R_Directory/library")
My question is, how can I write in the Rprofile.site and change the libPaths()?

Could you copy and add the error message you are getting when trying to edit? Then others with the same issue might find this post easier.

You need to change the file's permission.
Windows
You can use icacls (FYI If you are using a Windows version before XP see icacl) it has the following syntax:
icacls <filename> [/grant[:r] <sid>:<perm>[...]] [/deny <sid>:<perm>[...]] [/remove[:g|:d]] <sid>[...]] [/t] [/c] [/l] [/q] [/setintegritylevel <Level>:<policy>[...]]
icacls <directory> [/substitute <sidold> <sidnew> [...]] [/restore <aclfile> [/c] [/l] [/q]]

For your case you need something like:
icacls RProfile.site /grant YOUR_USERNAME:F
       ^                    ^             ^
       target file          |             |
                            taget user    |
                            (you)         Permission level F->Full, modify (M) or write (W) could also be enough

You can always type ICACLS /? to get the commands' help entry.
Linux
You can do that via terminal using the chmod command.
You can use it like this:
chmod 777 Rprofile.site
 

The numbers indicate the permission you want to give. 777 is the least restrictive meaning everyone can do everything with that file (read, write execute).
As to what the numbers exactly mean how-to-geek summarizes it as:

Numerical Shorthand
Another way to use chmod is to provide the permissions you wish to
give to the owner, group, and others as a three-digit number. The
leftmost digit represents the permissions for the owner. The middle
digit represents the permissions for the group members. The rightmost
digit represents the permissions for the others.
The digits you can use and what they represent are listed here:

0: (000) No permission.
1: (001) Execute permission.
2: (010) Write permission.
3: (011) Write and execute permissions.
4: (100) Read permission.
5: (101) Read and execute permissions.
6: (110) Read and write permissions.
7: (111) Read, write, and execute permissions.


You can check all files permission for the files in the folder you are currently in with ls -l.
Once you chnaged the permission for the file that you yourself have at least 6, you can edit the file using vim.

I have tried your command but I get an error: unexpected numeric constatnt in 777". I also checked the guide, but that one is for Linux and I am using Window system.

I added the windows command, see also this question.
